# Depth data works, but not in Background mode

Tags: python, image

As the titel says, I found a workaround for obtaining a depth image of the camera's FOV by using [this](https://ammous88.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/blender-access-render-results-pixels-directly-from-python-2/) workaround. It works just perfectly by accessing the pixel data of the image with python:

```
 pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels
```

BUT: This method works only when the GUI is used as well. In Background mode (using the attribute -b in cmd line) this does not work. The farest I got was to check if the image "has" some data with:

```
 pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].has_data
```

which gave me a clear false.  Therefore my question is, if there is a way how to enable this data also in Background mode?

I googled a lot and the only other option I found to access depth data, is to use the Camera Data Node's depth output. However, I do not know how to access this data via python script.

Comment: Could you resolve this issue? Did the answer *Sebastian Koch* posted help you? I am somehow trying to literally do what you are trying to do here. Could you take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102790/how-to-trigger-lmb-click-events-to-activate-a-specific-view-node-and-update-cont) and see if you can post a solution? The best think that came to my mind was to simulate mouse clicking, but it seems that it is not possible to do that either.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering of viewer nodes and previews in background mode was disabled in 2013 for speed optimization (see [here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Compositing_Nodes)). However, you can easily enable it again by modifying 2 files of the blender sources and compiling blender yourself (as described [here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender)).

In the file source/blender/compositor/operations/COM_ViewerOperation.h, line ~58:

```
bool isOutputOperation(bool /*rendering*/) const { if (G.background) return false; return isActiveViewerOutput();
```

should be changed to

```
bool isOutputOperation(bool /*rendering*/) const {return isActiveViewerOutput(); }
```

and in file source/blender/compositor/operations/COM_PreviewOperation.h, line ~48:

```
bool isOutputOperation(bool /*rendering*/) const { return !G.background; }
```

should be changed to

```
bool isOutputOperation(bool /*rendering*/) const { return true; }
```

After these changes, the pixels array gets properly updated in background mode.

Comment: I am somehow trying to literally do what the question asker here is trying to do here. Could you take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102790/how-to-trigger-lmb-click-events-to-activate-a-specific-view-node-and-update-cont) and see if you can post a solution? The best think that came to my mind was to simulate mouse clicking, but it seems that it is not possible to do that either. So I guess I need to somehow enable *backdrop* in the background mode instead. Do you think this would work?

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned and compiled Blender. Numpy can access the data but I cannot update "Viewer Node" image content, as mentioned in my previous post earlier. I need to somehow *activate* my Viewer nodes to be able to update the contents of the image block. Do you have any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: I would also go with @Scott Millner 's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102790/how-to-trigger-lmb-click-events-to-activate-a-specific-view-node-and-update-cont/102838#102838) to add a Switch Node that can be toggled. This is easy to implement and shouldn't add overhead as you mentioned (not sure about this, though). As you want to render millions of images, you probably want to parallelize the rendering anyways and run multiple blender instances in background mode.

Comment: I have already paralellized the rendering pipeline but I would like to store the rendering results in "Viewer Node" image block and use Numpy to read them. Unfortunately it seems that what Scott recommended does not work either and I cannot update the contents of the image block when running Blender in the background :(

Answer (score 0):

My solution into the new Blender Versions is:

```
def image_has_data(img):
    """Return True if the img has data"""
    if not img.has_data:
        try:
            img.update()
        except:
            return

    return True

if image_has_data(bpy.data.images['My Image']):
    print("The Image has data")
else:
    print("The Image has not data")
```

This will try to update the image and return the real status.