# Is it possible to enable backdrop using Python when running Blender without GUI?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I am trying to enable *backdrop* in Blender using Python and using **Blender's Python API** (no GUI) but it seems that it is not as straight-forward as I thought. I know how to enable **Use Nodes** via `bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True` and just need to enable backdrop. The most relevant Python documentation for *backdrop* [Here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SpaceNodeEditor.html#bpy.types.SpaceNodeEditor.show_backdrop) is a bit unclear and I do not know exactly how I can enable backdropping through the *NodeSpaceEditor* class. Can someone explain how I can do that?

Update: it turns out that the Python documentation is useful when you are running Blender with the GUI. I need to enable backdrop when I am running Blender in the background.

The hard way is to compile Blender from scratch and enable backdropping by modifying the source code as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72742/depth-data-works-but-not-in-background-mode) but this is too much of work. I hope there is a way to do it using Blender's Python API.

Comment: Do you see the python in the Info window as you change an editor to Node Editor and then change that to use a Compositor Node tree, and then tell it to 'use nodes' and 'show backdrop'? It is all of those and not just a single command that is involved here to use the backdrop, so we have to tell it to change or use each of those.

Comment: @CraigDJones Sorry I was assuming that we have done all of those steps except the backdrop part. Do you know how one can enable *backdrop* using Python in this case? I'm gonna update my question to make it clear.

Comment: Did you see the python in the info editor? bpy.context.space_data.show_backdrop = True
This is what pops up, so it tells me that if I am in the Node Editor already and in the Compositor Node tree, then this allows me to tell it to use the back drop.

Comment: I believe you will have to switch to the correct editor first and meet all those requirements first, since just running that as a command on its own causes an error since the text editor doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: @CraigDJones Sorry I'm a bit confused. I think I'm getting what you are saying but I don't know how I can do the switching the way you describe. Could you post an answer and describe how I should do that, kind of step-by-step? Really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share what code you have so far so that I can see how to approach what you are doing? I am not the best, but I might help find the answers to fit the script you are building.

Comment: @CraigDJones I don't have a long script. I just do `bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True` to use nodes and the next thing I need to do is to enable backdrop using one or more lines of Python code, which I don't know how to do as of now.

Comment: Loathe to answer your questions because there is always some caveat, like by python do you mean running bpy as a python module?. Quite simply the backdrop in your first link can be set via `context.space_data.use_backdrop = True` as long as the `context.area.type == 'NODE_EDITOR'` otherwise loop screen areas and if node editor type use `area.spaces.active`

Comment: @batFINGER Sorry that my questions have some caveats but I have to ask what I have in my mind somehow and I sometimes forget/cannot to explain everything the way everyone expect, maybe because of my wrong assumptions. I will try to be more clear from now onwards. Yes I meant running python as a module. When I do `import bpy` I do not have access to `bpy.context.space_data.use_backdrop` or `bpy.context.area.type` but I can set `area.type` to `NODE_EDITOR` when I am using the Desktop version of Blender. Any ideas on how I can do it when using the Python module? Thank you

Comment: Not sure I see the point of wanting a UI backdrop when running without a UI.

Comment: @batFINGER Sorry for the confusion. I didn't even know that the first link was pointing to a part of the documentation that is relevant to UI. I'm still newish to Blender so please bare with me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set this property, you just have to know which area is the node editor. Like this:

```
import bpy

def get_node_editor_area():
    """
    Get the index of the area containing the compositor
    """
    for i in range(len(bpy.context.screen.areas)):
        area = bpy.context.screen.areas[i]
        if area.type == 'NODE_EDITOR':
            return i

area_index = get_node_editor_area()
bpy.context.screen.areas[area_index].spaces[0].show_backdrop = True
```

If this is for an addon and the user will have the mouse in the node editor area when this function is called, I think you could use `bpy.context.space_data.show_backdrop = True` instead.

Comment: This seems to be only working when you are running Desktop (with UI) version of Blender. I couldn't run this when using Blender as module or when running Blender in the background.   Did you also try doing that? When I print `area.type` in the `for` loop I get the followings: `INFO, PROPERTIES ,TIMELINE, OUTLINER, VIEW_3D`. When running with the GUI I also get `NODE_EDITOR`.

Comment: Why do you want to show the backdrop without running Blender's user interface? For my script to work, one of the areas open in blender must be the node editor.

Comment: Well I do not really need Backdrop to see something (because I cannot). I need to enable backdrop so that I can update the contents of the `Viewer Node` image block. Maybe you can take a look at my problem [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102790/how-to-trigger-lmb-click-events-to-activate-a-specific-view-node-and-update-cont?noredirect=1&lq=1); this might give you an idea of what I'm trying to do. [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72742/depth-data-works-but-not-in-background-mode) is also a bit relevant. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't know much about running python in Blender without a UI, but have you tried setting one of the areas of Blender's UI to the Node Editor, then saving the startup file, then trying my script? Or perhaps loading a .blend file with one of the areas set to the Node editor when you run blender from the terminal.